# Is the XMLNS attribute for SVGs valid in HTML5?

Tags: xml, html, validation, svg

I'm a huge fan of using SVG's inline for vector icons and similar use cases. Recently, while testing in Internet Explorer 8 I found that the presence of the xmlns attribute caused the HTML5Shiv to fail. I submitted an issue report (https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/issues/167) only to receive the snarky answer that XML doesn't belong in HTML5.

SVG, while XML, seems to have been accepted as a best practice and is often recommended for use in HTML5 so the response I got seems silly.

My question is whether or not the XMLNS is valid for use in HTML5? Most tutorials seem to recommend it (even HTML5Rocks: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/svg/mobile_fundamentals/) and I haven't found anything telling me that it is invalid in HTML5 besides its ability to break the HTML5Shiv.

The second part to my question is whether it would cause harm to remove that attribute. If I remove the "xmlns" attribute what errors may I see in different browsers?

I have removed it from my code and see no issues but I want to double check.

EDIT

I'm including the HTML/XML that was causing the issue. Please note that the issue was fixed by simply removing the "xmlns" part.

```
 <header>
   <div>
     <a href="#navigation" class="page_nav_btn" id="navBtn" >
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="18" viewBox="0" version="1.1">
         <switch>
           <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
             <g transform="translate(-1.000000, 0.000000)" fill="#FFFFFF">
               <rect x="0" y="0" width="23" height="3"/>
               <rect x="0" y="7" width="23" height="3"/>
               <rect x="0" y="14" width="23" height="3"/>
             </g>
           </g>
           <foreignObject>
             MENU
           </foreignObject>
        </switch>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Actually, I answered your question: https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/issues/167#issuecomment-53069093. I can not replicate this issue, if you use valid polyglot markup in conjunction with the xmlns attribute. I can see an issue, if the code doesn't satisfy polyglot markup, but still uses the xmlns attribute. So if this is causing your problem, I don't consider it an html5shiv issue. But I need more information.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, thank you. Removing that line did the trick and didn't appear to cause any other errors. I'll put the original code below if you would like to look at it. Again, this issue only appeared in IE8

Comment: Yes, I need the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It's allowed in the sense that any random attribute is allowed but it is otherwise [ignored](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#namespaces) by html parsers in documents served as text/html

Comment: I more or less know that. However, it seems to be commonly recommended to include it even with text/html documents. To be more specific I'm wondering why its so often recommended if HTML5 ignores it.

Comment: It's required if you have standalone SVG documents served as image/svg+xml or text/xml it's recommended by those who cargo cult that requirement to html

Comment: @Zack The [current HTML5 specs suggest](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/embedded-content-0.html#svg): "interactive HTML user agents are encouraged to provide a way to export any SVG fragment as an XML namespace-well-formed XML fragment"; i.e., the HTML5 agent should have a way to insert all the namespaces, close all the tags and quote all the attributes.  But that's not common, so having clean XML code that you can cut and paste into a stand-alone SVG file is often useful.  It shouldn't cause problems as a default namespace declaration, but you can't use custom prefixes in HTML5.